# Set a boolean from buttonGroup (vue-strap)

Tags: vue.js, vue-strap

I try to use the component *buttonGroup* from the library [vue-strap](https://wffranco.github.io/vue-strap/#button-group) as a toggle but I can't get it work. I succeed to set string value but not boolean value.

Here is the code

```
<button-group v-model="radioValue" type="primary">
  <radio selected-value="true">Correct</radio>
  <radio selected-value="false">Incorrect</radio>
</button-group>
```

The variable *radioValue* is updated correctly and set to "true" or "false" (string). But now I'd like to set a boolean instead (true or false).

I tried to make a [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NvRWMM) but I can't get it work neither. If it was working, I would tell you to open the console and execute *vm.radioValue*, click on Incorrect and execute *vm.radioValue* a second time. You will see that a string is set instead of a boolean.

I tried to bind the value (`:select-value="true"`). It kind of work but when the user clic on "Correct", the other button (Incorrect) is also active. Maybe it's a bug from vue-strap...

Comment: true is interpreted as a string

Comment: @Reiner yup, indeed, I'd like it to be interpreted as a boolean

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42138518/components-of-vuestrap-not-working-with-vue2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a major part of your problem is that you're using vue-strap for Vue 1 (at least in your CodePen).

Since the button-group works with string values and you want a boolean value, you should make a settable computed to use as a proxy, to convert between string and boolean. Then v-model that proxy value in your button-group.

You can also make a component to hide the proxying, see the `boolean-button-group` in my snippet.

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  components: {
    'buttonGroup': VueStrap.buttonGroup,
    'radio': VueStrap.radio,
    'booleanButtonGroup': {
      template: '<button-group v-model="proxyValue" :type="type"><slot></slot></button-group>',
      props: {
        type: {},
        value: {
          type: Boolean
        }
      },
      computed: {
        proxyValue: {
          get() { return this.value.toString(); },
          set(stringValue) { this.$emit('input', stringValue === 'true'); }
        }
      },
      components: {
        buttonGroup: VueStrap.buttonGroup
      }
    }
  },
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    radioValue: false
  },
  computed: {
    proxyRadioValue: {
      get() {
        return this.radioValue.toString();
      },
      set(stringValue) {
        this.radioValue = stringValue === 'true';
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.6/vue.js"></script>
<script src="//rawgit.com/wffranco/vue-strap/master/dist/vue-strap.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <button-group v-model="proxyRadioValue" type="primary">
        <radio selected-value="true">Correct</radio>
        <radio selected-value="false">Incorrect</radio>
      </button-group>
      {{radioValue}}
      {{radioValue ? 'yes' : 'no'}}
    </div>
    <div class="row">
    <boolean-button-group v-model="radioValue" type="info">
      <radio selected-value="true">Correct</radio>
      <radio selected-value="false">Incorrect</radio>
    </boolean-button-group>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great job! 1) I didn't know it was possible to import a script from git like this. 2) Is there a way to proxify globally ? Like add a modifier "boolean" ? I have a lot of button-group. I will research around this

Comment: oh I see, you created a component "above" the existing one, that's very clever. I think I am going to use this method. But I still get one question. Do you know why the component buttonGroup itself, does not interpret boolean value correctly? When I look at the [code](https://github.com/wffranco/vue-strap/blob/master/src/Radio.vue) I can't see anything wrong. Besides, if I leave the selected-value arg blanck, true (a real boolean) it set correctly

Comment: My guess is that the `selected-value` prop is defined as a string.

Comment: I suppose it is, do you why?

Comment: I do not know why.

Comment: In [buttonGroup.vue](https://github.com/wffranco/vue-strap/blob/master/src/Radio.vue#L38), the `selectedValue` prop does not have any type, so it should work with boolean. I think I am missing something...

Comment: If it's not defined as boolean, and you pass it `"true"`, though, that's a string. You would have to `v-bind` it to a boolean. I tried `:selected-value="true"`, but that didn't work. Possibly a boolean variable would work.

Comment: Yup! That's what I said in the last sentence of my post (using `v-bind` does not work). I'd like to understand why because writing a component above is a just a workaround and does to solve the "real" problem.